# Adding a prefixed "period" before a variable, jQuery

Tags: jquery, variables, prefix

I'm trying to add a period "." and the suffix "-on" to a variable (line 4 below):

```
    function globalProducts(cat, self){
    $("div.info").hide();
    $(self).addClass(cat+'-on');
    $(".product-stats li :not('.'+cat+'-on')").removeClass();
}

$("li.stat-cat1 a").live('click', function() {
    globalProducts('stat-cat1',this);
    $(".ingredients").show();
    return false;
});
```

The code lints but it doesn't work in practice. Something is wrong. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the syntax highlighting:

```
$(".product-stats li :not('.'+cat+'-on')").removeClass();
```

Your quotes are wrong, it should be:

```
$(".product-stats li :not(." + cat + "-on)").removeClass();
```

.

Comment: Yup! Indeed it is. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".product-stats li :not('.'+cat+'-on')").removeClass();
```

Should be

```
$(".product-stats li :not('."+cat+"-on')").removeClass();
```